# Byte-code java virtual machine

Tags: java, jvm, antlr, bytecode

our project is to create intermediate code for our grammar which is miniJava.
till now we build the lexer and parser for it using antlr.
now for the intermediate code we should use Byte code. can anyone help me understand what byte code is and what should we do to use it?
 I've searched through the web, there wasn't much resources on this case.

Comment: Generating byte code is a non-trivial think to do. This is very advanced topic.  I suggest you use a library like ASM to help you do this. Even if the byte code looks right to you, doesn't mean the JVM will accept it.

Comment: The JVM spec is the place to go.  It's pretty ugly in places, though, and the real JVM is *very* picky.  Are you sure you're supposed to use the JVM bytecode scheme, or just something like it?

Comment: If you do target the JVM, set your class file version to something prior to 50, so that you do not have to tangle with the "stack map".

Comment: yeah,we should create byte code  for our grammar using Jasmin tool

Comment: @Peter I've written tools that generate classfiles directly as well as  hand assembling classes in a hex editor. It's not that hard. Admittedly, it's probably beyond someone who can't even find the JVM spec.

Answer (score 3):

### [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)

In documentation **bytecodes** are often described as **instructions**.

> Chapter 6 specifies the instruction set of the Java Virtual Machine, presenting the **instructions** in alphabetical order of opcode mnemonics.

### [Chapter 6. The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html)

> A Java Virtual Machine instruction consists of an opcode specifying the operation to be performed, followed by zero or more operands embodying values to be operated upon. This chapter gives details about the format of each Java Virtual Machine instruction and the operation it performs.

Complete bytecode list: [Instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5)

### [4.10.1.3. Instruction Representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.3)

> Individual **bytecode instructions** are represented in Prolog as terms whose functor is the name of the instruction and whose arguments are its parsed operands.
>
> For example, an aload instruction is represented as the term aload(N), which includes the index N that is the operand of the instruction.

### Other resources

- [Java bytecode:
  Understanding bytecode makes you a better programmer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/)
- [Java Bytecode Fundamentals](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html)
- [CS1Bh Lecture Note 7, Compilation I: Java Byte Code](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/teaching/cs1/CS1/Bh/Notes/JavaByteCode.pdf)
- [Java bytecode veriﬁcation: algorithms and formalizations](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Exleroy/publi/bytecode-verification-JAR.pdf)